# Accessing Object instead of Array Element

Tags: java, object

In my code i want to access array first element CIS 400 and check whether it's equal to supplied string or not, but it is accessing whole array object. Can any one give me clue how to do it..thanks...

```
 public class Course1 {
      public static void main(String[] args){

         int check=   GetCourseByCourseID("CIS 400");

         if (check==0){
           System.out.print("Don't match");
         }

     }

    private static  int GetCourseByCourseID(String CourseID) {

       for ( int i = 0; i < course.CourseArray.length; i++ ){ 
          if ( CourseID.equals(course.CourseArray[i] )){                   
               return 1;
          }
          else {
              System.out.print(course.CourseArray[1]);  
              return 0;

         }
        // ToDO

       }
       return 2;

   }

   Course1(String string, String string2, int i, String string3, String string4){ 
        CourseID = "CIS 400"; 
        CourseTitle = ""; 
        CreditHours = 0; 
        Description = ""; 
        PrerequisiteCourseID = "";

       };

    }


    class course {
      static Course1[] CourseArray ={

        new Course1 ("CIS 400", "OO Analysis & Design", 4, "Important class", "CIS 110"),

        new Course1 ("CIS 150A" , "VB.NET Programming", 4, "Good Introduction to     programming", "CIS 100") ,

        new Course1 ("CIS 150B", "C# Programming with labs", 4, "Follow-up to CIS 100", "CIS 100")

      };
   }
```

Comment: Please reformat your code. It's currently unreadable due to odd indentation, bracing positioning, and line spacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're comparing whole array instead of individual array element. `If` condition needs to be like below to compare first string of the array

```
if ( CourseID.equals(course.CourseArray[i].string ))
```

`CourseArray[i]` returns `Course1` object. To access its property, use `CourseArray[i].string` but you need to declare it `string` which i dont see in your sample.

You've defined a constructor for `Course1` but you need to also define class variables and then assign values passed through constructor to class variables

Answer (score 0):

What about variables you initialize in constructor? I suppose they're private class fields? In that case just override toString method of Course1 to return CourseID.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit weird. Where are declared the private fields ?
Otherwise, I think your condition should be:

```
if (CourseID.equals (course.CourseArray[i].courseID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 10    private static  int GetCourseByCourseID(String CourseID) {
 11   
 12          for ( int i = 0; i < course.CourseArray.length; i++ ){ 
 13             if ( CourseID.equals(course.CourseArray[i] )){                   
 14                  return 1;
 15             }
 16             else {
 17                 System.out.print(course.CourseArray[1]);  
 18                 return 0;
 19            }
 20          }
 21          return 2;
 22      }
```

You have few problems in this code.

Line 13: 
   You compare the parameters `courseID`, with whole `Course1` object. This will return always false.

Line 12: The loop will run only once as you return in `if` and `else` block.

Line 17: In this line you print whole object at position `1`.

Below you have potential implementation that you may analyse

```
private static Course1 findCourseByID(String id) {

    for(Course1 course : getCourses()) {
        if(id.equals(course.CourseID)) {
           return course;
        }
     }
     return null;
}
```